# Running mulitple nodes from a Bash file

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have single C++ code which gets the node name from the arguments passed to the main function. This is so that I can use the same code to run multiple nodes.
Is there a way to run multiple nodes in a single script file? Where the name of node is assigned when the main is executed?

```
rosrun machine sensors sens1 1
```

This needs to be run for different inputs on different terminals. I tried using a single .sh file, but until the first node exits, the next one isn't started. Is there a way to bypass this issue such that I can run multiple nodes using a single script on multiple terminals?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253070/running-mulitple-nodes-from-a-bash-file/) by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you'll want to look at [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch).

See [Clearpath Robotics - ROS Tutorials - Launch Files](https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ros/Launch%20Files.html) for a starter tutorial.

PS: have you done the ROS tutorials on the wiki?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-01-26**:
I have seen roslaunch from the tutorials. But in my case, I am entering the node name at runtime, can i adapt that to roslaunch?

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-02-01**:
Thank you, I created a launch file with parameters to run the nodes as suggested in the starter tutorial!